# show diff between diverged github branches?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I have two github branches, let's call them 'alt' and 'master'.
'Alt' was created from master, and has several additional commits.
Meanwhile, several other commits have been pushed to 'master', diverging the two branches.
Now, I understand that I could try *merging* them back, potentially fixing conflicts manually (and I know that there will be lots of conflicts).
The question is: can I see the diff and/or potential merge conflicts visually using github UI? Or I have to use some other tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git mergetool` after merge failure. Mergetool available like: `meld`, `kdiff3`, `bcompare`, `p4merge`

```
git mergetool [--tool=<tool>]
```

or you can set in global config.

```
git config --global merge.tool [tool]
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that seeing the diff between the branches is somewhat a different thing from seeing potential conflicts, because conflicts have to do with the relationship between each branch's diff *from the merge base*.

Especially if you're wanting to work through a particular GUI, which might make it harder to use uncommon commands, it seems like the easiest way to see potential conflicts is to initiate the merge.  You can always abort the merge once you've seen what you need to see.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this via the `Compare` UI.

Fill in the `<org>` and `<reponame>` in the URL below to view a comparison between your `master` and `alt` branches:

`https://github.com/<org>/<reponame>/compare/master...alt`

Comment: It seems that in this case the comparison would be against their common ancestor (right before alt was created), and not the latest version of master.